# Hibernate Table per Subclass approach - mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, join, hibernate-onetomany

I have a table hierarchy like

Job{jobId, title} with One to Many relation with

Task{taskId, jobId(FK), task_title} with One to Many relation with

SubTask{subTaskId, TaskId(FK), subtask_title}.

Now I have a subset of tables which extend these above primary tables like

TechinalJob{jobId(FK), Technical_Details},

TechinalTask{taskId(FK), Technical_Task_Details},

TechinalSubTask{subTaskId(FK), Technical_SubTask_Details}.

Similarly I will have Administrative Jobs/Tasks/SubTasks.

But the catch is I dont have a relation ship between Techincal Jobs/Tasks/SubTasks or Administrative ones.. The relationship is through original Job/Task/SubTask. I dont have primary keys in Techincal Jobs/Tasks/SubTasks or Administrative ones either. So If I have to create a  bidirectional one-to-many relationship between TechinalJob and TechincalTask I have to go through the Job/Task/SubTask table structure do the following. How can I achieve this using Hibernate inheritance.

**Update 03/25/2015:**

After trying ver2 suggested by Zielu. This is the revised code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Job")    
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public class Job {  

    @Id
    private int jobId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="job")  
    protected Set<? extends Task> tasks;
    public Set<? extends Task> getTasks(
        return tasks;
    );

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Task")    
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public class Task { 

    @Id
    private int taskId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobId", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    public Job job;

    public Job getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(Job job)   {
        this.job= job;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TechinalJob")    
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="jobId")  
public class TechincalJob extends Job { 

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="job") 
   Set<TechincalTask> tasks;

   @Override
   public Set<TechnicalTask> getTasks() {
       return (Set<TechnicalTask>)tasks;
   };

   @Column(name="Technical_Details")
   private Integer Technical_Details;

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TechincalTask")    
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="taskId")  
public class TechincalTask extends Task {

    public TechincalJob getJob() {
        return (TechincalJob)job;
    }

    @Column(name="Technical_Task_Details")
    private Integer Technical_Task_Details;

}
```

When I tried this I got an exception saying  **Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: TechinalTask.job in TechincalJob.tasks**. It is not able to find job in TechnicalTask though I am extending Task and making sure job in Task is public.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please include the whole code for the beans with full all the annotations. I believe You misunderstood the jpa inheritance but I would need to see the whole code to check it.

Comment: Thanks, Zielu, I added more information to my question, please let me know if I have missed something that might be important to debug this problem. I excluded subTask because it will be the same as Job-Task relationship and will make the already long question longer..

Comment: Since you mentioned `But the catch is I don't have a relation ship between Techincal Jobs/Tasks/SubTasks or Administrative ones.. The relationship is through original Job/Task/SubTask.` the tables Job, Task, Subtask only holds the relationship between Technical and Admin counterparts. So what is is that you want to achieve ? You will have to spell that out. Once you do that also state if your tables are open for redesign like adding any column etc. ?

Comment: Bhantol, I would like to get the hibernate mapping working without any modifications to my tables (No additional columns). I wonder if there is a way to avoid the above mentioned exception.

Comment: this is hibernate issue, sorry i normally using eclipse link and everything worked but with hibernate I could not make it run. For hibernate you need either live with not typed relationship or have extra column for foreign key in you subtask tables.

Comment: ok have last idea how it can be done with hiber but it depends if the task and job tables have extra columns apart from primary/foreign keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Zielu, I appreciate all your effort in helping me out.. I finally found a solution. But it is not through hibernate inheritance.. I used combination of SecondaryTable and java inheritance. The way I did it is by making superclass @MappedSuperClass and making the child object use the parent's table as @Table and child's table as @SecondaryTable

```
@MappedSuperClass
public class Job <J extends Job, T extends Task,> {  

    @Id
    private int jobId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="job")  
    protected Set<T> tasks;
    public Set<T> getTasks(
        return tasks;
    );

}

@MappedSuperClass
public class Task <T extends Task, J extends Job> {  

    @Id
    private int taskId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobId", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    public J job;
    public J getJob() {
        return job;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table("Job")
@SecondaryTable("TechinalJob")    
public class TechnicalJob extends Job<TechnicalJob, TechnicalTask> {  

   //get all relations from parent and additional columns
}

@Entity
@Table("Task")
@SecondaryTable("TechinalTask")
public class TechnicalTask extends Task<TechnicalTask, TechnicalJob> {  

   //get all relations from parent and additional columns

}
```

And to write a common query for both Task and TechnicalTask I am planning to use Criteria. In my DAO I will have something like

```
public class JobDAO <J extends Job> {

    protected Class<? extends Job> jobClass = Job.class;

    public List<J> getJobs(int id) {
        return (List<T>)(entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)).createCriteria(jobClass, "j").list();
    }
}

public class TaskDAO <T extends Task> {
    public List<T> getTasks
}
```

---

```
public class TechnicalJobDAO extends JobDAO<TechnicalJob> {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        jobClass = TechnicalJob.class;
    }
    //get all parents methods
}

public class TechnicalTaskDAO extends TaskDAO<TechnicalTaskk> {
    //get all parents methods
}
```

Implicit polymorphism in hibernate was another reason why I did not go for HQL queries despite their elegance. Now I am loosing on querying directly on Job and Task, but that would have not worked even if I went with Hibernate Table per subclass inheritance because of implicit polymorphism.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you are trying to achieve.

You mention extending tables in DB but there is not such thing like subtables in SQL that is Java concept, so lets look at it from the Java point. And apology in advance if I wrote about obvious things to you (the closest thing to your solution is at the end of point 1).

1. You have Job and its subclasses. Each job has list of Tasks. Task also has its subclasses. The TechnicalJobs have always TechnicalTask in them.

so you would have code:

```
//ver1    
class Job {

    public abstract Set<? extends Task> getTasks();
}

class TechnicalJob extends Job {
    Set<TechnicalTask> tasks = new HashSet<>();
    @Override
    public Set<TechnicalTask> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    };
}
```

or

```
//ver2
class Job {
    Set<? extends Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();
    public Set<? extends Task> getTasks(
        return tasks;
    );
}

class TechnicalJob extends Job {
    @Override
    public Set<TechnicalTask> getTasks() {
        return (Set<TechnicalTask>)tasks;
    };
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
TechnicalJob tj = ...;
Job jn = jt;
for (Task t : jn.getTasks()) t.doSomething();
for (TechnicalTask t: jt.getTasks()) t.doSomethingTechnical();
```

Now, the DB structure you mentioned looks more like ver2, you have the relationship column in table for Task which would "translate" to the Set<> tasks field in Job (you could have defined a join table JobTask instead which would be exactly equivalent of the tasks field).

So you don't need extra mapping in your sub-Jobs, sub-Tasks. Simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Job")    
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public class Job {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    int jobId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="job")  
    Set<Task> tasks;

    public Set<? extends Task> getTasks() {
        if (tasks == null) tasks = new HashSet<>();
        return tasks;
    }
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "TechinalJob")    
public class TechinalJob extends Job {  

    @Override
    public Set<TechincalTask> getTasks() {
        return (Set<TechincalTask>)super.getTasks();
    }
}
```

You provide type safety (that only `TechnicalTasks` got into `TechnicalJo`b) by typed accessed method for example `addTask(TechnicalTask task)` in `TechnicalJob`. It mimics your DB structure, in which nothing stops you from having a row in Task table that is linked to a TechnicalJob but which is also joing with record in Administrative task so it is not really TechnicalTask.

If you are in charge of the schema, since you are already using inheritance strategy JOIN, you may consider having Ver1 approach, so no mapping in the Job/Task class (only abstract getters). And mapping in individual subclasses. That will provide better type control, but the joinColumn will be in Task subtables.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Job")    
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public abstract class Job {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    int jobId;
    public abstract Set<? extends Task> getTasks();
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "Task")    
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public class Task { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    int taskId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TechinalJob")    
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="jobId")  
public class TechinalJob extends Job {  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="job")
    Set<TechincalTask> tasks;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TechincalTask")    
public class TechincalTask extends Task {   

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobId")
    TechinalJob job;
}
```

And finally build on top of it, the closest match to what you were trying to achieve == joinColumn in Task table, subTypes of Tasks in specific Jobs. Task maps to Job, but Job do not map to Task only subJobs have mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Job")    
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public abstract class Job {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    int jobId;

    public abstract Set<? extends Task> getTasks();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TechinalJob")    
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="jobId")  
public class TechinalJob extends Job {  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="job") //you need the mapped by, it was missing in your code
    Set<TechincalTask> tasks;

    @Column(name="Technical_Details")
    Integer Technical_Details;

    @Override
    public Set<TechincalTask> getTasks() {
        if (tasks == null) tasks = new HashSet<>();   
        return tasks;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Task")    
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public class Task { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    int taskId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobId")
    Job job;   
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TechincalTask")    
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="taskId")  
public class TechincalTask extends Task {   

    //you don't define relationship to Job it comes from the parrent

    @Column(name="Technical_Task_Details")
    Integer Technical_Task_Details;

    public TechnicalJob getJob() {
        return (TechnicalJob)job;

}
```

**EDIT** 
The above code **works with EclipseLink but not Hibernate**. As Adithye noticed the exception is thrown due to missing mapping target.

2. You have Jobs and its Subclesses, Each job has list of Tasks and each SubJob has list of General Tasks and another list of specialized tasks for example TechnicalTasks. Your Java code kind of was suggestin it as Job had Taks and TechnicalJobs had Tasks (inhereited from Job) and its own technicalTasks collection.

In that case they have to be mapped to different join tables, as otherwise both collections will hold the same values.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an elaborate response.. I truly appreciate it.. It worked like a charm, but I had to add targetEntity in each of the oneToMany and ManyToOne annotations..

Comment: Actually I revisited the logic and found a few concerns, In TechnicalTask you said that you will get the Job from the parent instead of declaring TechincalJob. When I compiled this and started the server it gave and exception, Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: TechinalTask.job in TechincalJob.tasks . Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: The next concern is when I am writing HQL I have to say TechinalJob tj inner join fetch tj.tasks. This will join job with all the tasks children (TechincalTask, AdministrativeTask) due to hibernate's implicit polymorphism.

Comment: In which approach (1,2,3?) I have tested all three and they worked (I used EclipseLInk not hibernate but the features used are only standard JPA.

Comment: The mapped by was probably caused by your private modificator on job/tasks. If it is private it is not visible in the subclass and cannot be mappedBy. I use package private .

Comment: Some more information on first concern. I tried it in a different way and since having a concrete implementation of Job was a requirement I went with ver2 that you have mentioned on top and now I am getting org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Fail to process type argument in a generic declaration. Member : Job#tasks  Type: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl. I am not sure if this is a hibernate specific thing.

Comment: Could you make edit and add your new code at the end (rather add then replace so others can advice you on original code). Or post it somewhere so I can have a look. Without seeing it, the fields have to have concrete type not generic (so Set<Job> not Set<? extends Job>)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73791/discussion-between-adithya-puram-and-zielu).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73821/discussion-between-adithya-puram-and-zielu).